# Adding a Mock Object to a List

Tags: java, list, testing, mockito

Currently I am trying create 10 mock objects of the same class for a test using Mockito in Java;

```
@Mock Bird bird1;

@Mock Bird bird2;

...

@Mock Bird bird10;
```

and I try to put these mock objects in a list since I will need to access them in a for loop to write their `when-thenReturns` and some other stuff like assigning all of these birds a name. However, when I try to do this it gives me a `NullPointerException`. It kind of makes sense that it gives that error, however I desperately try to find a way around for this and access these 10 mocks from some kind of a list or iterable. Is that possible?

Edit:
Since @dawood-ibn-karem @pedro-luiz @tgdavies has asked for some more code, let me give it.

```
protected ArrayList<Bird> birds = new ArrayList<>();

  @Test
  public void testBirds() {
    // Arrange
    birdsListSetter();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      String voice= VoiceFixture.newRandomChirp();
      when(birds.get(i).getChirp()).thenReturn(voice);            
      }
    }
    // there some other stuff after this but the error occurs up here
  }

  public void birdsListSetter() {
    birds.add(bird1);
    birds.add(bird2);
    birds.add(bird3);
    birds.add(bird4);
    birds.add(bird5);
    birds.add(bird6);
    birds.add(bird7);
    birds.add(bird8);
    birds.add(bird9);
    birds.add(bird10);
  }
```

When I run the test, it fails at the first when-thenReturn saying that

```
NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Bird.getChirp()" because the return value of "java.util.ArrayList.get(int)" is null
```

Comment: Could you post your current attempt ? It is better for us when trying to test it... for example, providing the Bird class, test class that you are creating those mocks and etc...

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  How are you creating your list?  How are you adding the mocks to the list?  Please show some code.

Comment: If you need to create many mocks of the same type you may want to use `mock(Bird.class)` in a loop, instead of annotations.

Comment: @PedroLuiz You can think of the Bird class has a getChirp method only, I have added the test up to the point it fails.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The implementations are now partly added in the edit.

Comment: @tgdavies I need to assign different chirps to each of these mock objects and assert some other stuff using these differently assigned chirps. When I create in a loop, I believe it doesn't do what I want to do.

Comment: What runner are you using for the test? Is it Mockito-aware? Anyway, you can just remove `bird1-10` and put `birds.add(mock(Bird.class));` in your loop just before your `when`.

Comment: How are you initialising your mocks? - There are a few options, like calling `mock` explicitly, calling `initMocks`, using an appropriate test runner, or using a JUnit rule.  There are advantages and disadvantages to each.  But you need to pick one of these, or you won't have any mocks.

Answer (score 0):

I was basically thinking that adding @Mock was enough for initializing, but apparently I was wrong. Editing the code as

```
@Mock Bird bird1=mock(Bird.class)
```

fixed my problem. Thanks to kind helpers!

Answer (score 0):

Even though @saarantras answered that he solved his problem, I wanted to point it out that

```
@Mock Bird bird1=mock(Bird.class)
```

Is not the recommended usage @Mock and Mockito.mock().

**@Mock**

```
@Mock Bird bird1
```

**Mockito.mock()**

```
Bird bird1=mock(Bird.class)
```

> Mockito.mock() method and @Mock annotation are doing slightly the
> same, which is defining a mock object in unit tests. However, there
> are some differences.

I'm not going into those differences, but you can have a look at

[Mockito.mock() vs @Mock vs @MockBean](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean)

One thing that makes that NullPointerException happen is forgetting to add

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BirdTest {

@Mock Bird bird1;
@Mock Bird bird2;
@Mock Bird bird3;
@Mock Bird bird4;
@Mock Bird bird5;
@Mock Bird bird6;
@Mock Bird bird7;
@Mock Bird bird8;
@Mock Bird bird9;
@Mock Bird bird10;
```

At you test class level, wich isn't required when using **Mockito.mock()**